# Unable to install 11.10 to a new OCZ Agility 3 SSD

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, thinkpad

I know the discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd) where they are not getting the same error as me.

I use Lenovo ThinkPad X60.

The default partition table: sd1 ext4 53.91GB, sd2 extended 1.99GB and sd5 swap 1.99GB.

I get `Input/output error during read on`/dev/sda` when trying to install from live CD -mode and when trying to install directly. I get the error normally at the stage of choosing time zone or very last at choosing the keyboard layout. Then there is the box with buttons: Back, Ignore and Continue. None of them enable the procedure to go forward, so I need to cancel it.

How can you install Ubuntu to an SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSD contains more electronics than an usual hdd, be sure that the firmware of your SSD is up to date otherwise this can be considered "a normal behaviour"; from this point of view the standard hdd are way more reliable than an SSD.

check the download page for your product http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-agility-3-sata-iii-2-5-ssd.html

Comment: The easiest way to solve the problem at this time is to buy Intel's  quality SSD drives, since OCZ has severe problems in heat management. The sleep of OCZ is just awful in relation to Intel.