# installation on SSD

Tags: installation, 12.04, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd)

I want to install new 12.04 on OCZ Vertex3 disk. Do I need make proper partition alignment or something like that? Some people say that modern SSDs and Linux distros don't require any special manipulations for that case, some people say that I still need to play with fdisk. What to do?

Comment: You don't need anything special.

Have a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd

Comment: Have a search on AU for the word "trim" :)