# Tiny ssd for two OS?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I 've got a new hp laptop with windows 10 preinstalled. It has only 128 gb ssd and i want to dual boot it with ubuntu 16.04.Is there enough space for this and if there is how much space should i give to the partitions?
Thank you anyway.
P.S:And something else.Do i have to make a swap partition ?

Comment: See [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) and [Do I need swap with new SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178661/do-i-need-swap-with-new-ssd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I suggest that you give Ubuntu 28 GB (and leave 100 GB for Windows).
- You need not have a swap partition, if there is 4 GB RAM (or more). But if you have many tabs open in your web browser or do something that needs a lot of RAM, it is a good idea to have a small swap partition, maybe only 1 or 2 GB. You will notice that the computer gets slow - and you can close some tabs in the web browser. You can also run **htop** to monitor how the memory is used. It is a bad idea to rely heavily on swap on an SSD due to wear, so you should avoid swapping, only use it as a buffer for unusual situations.

-o-

- Shrink the Windows partition with Windows tools (when running Windows). Leave the unallocated space.
- Boot from your Ubuntu install drive 'Try Ubuntu'
- Start **gparted** and create an ext4 partition (to become the root partition '/' of Ubuntu) and a small swap partition.
- Start the **installer**, and at the partitioning window, select **Something else** and install Ubuntu into the partitions that you created for it.
- With Windows 10 preinstalled you are running in UEFI mode, and the bootloader will be installed automatically using the already existing EFI partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done, technically even on 64GB. But it's very tight in space. I'd give windows at least 25GB and Ubuntu at least 12GB. The rest of the room you can assign how you want, based on what OS you'll wat to sore and install most things on. A swap space of a few gigs is always necessary. You could also make a partition out of the rest for shared storage in exFAT. Or buy a >32GB USB and install Ubuntu on that .

Answer (score 0):

i have MacBook with **120 GB** Flash storage. Mostly Linux needs at least 5 GB and a fresh Windows 10 should take 20 GB hard disk. If you dont have too heavy apps such as **Adobe apps, games or Visual Studio with add-ons** it will be no harm to spear **20-30 GB space.** Currently i am using Ubuntu 16.04 with 38 GB space and i am using only 5.7 GB space.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  9,5M  780M   2% /run
/dev/sda2        36G  5,3G   29G  16% /
tmpfs           3,9G  564K  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       196M  4,8M  192M   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs           789M  100K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1        76G   66G   11G  86% /media/egrimo/Egrimo
```

My main macOS part is sda1 and my bootloader is sda5. Rest is the Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

128 GB SSD is plenty for dual boot. Windows 10 requires 16 GB, while Ubuntu 16.04 requires 5 GB. I would set aside 32 GB for Windows and at least 16 GB for Ubuntu.

Comment: You are quite the optimist, aren't you? Things are very different in the real world of actual usage of either OS.

Comment: You obviously don't understand the meaning of minimum requirements. I'm actually running Ubuntu on a 16 GB SSD and my Windows operating system currently uses around 25 GB.