# Ubuntu laptop boot without USB or CD

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot

I would like to load Ubuntu onto my old laptop but it will only boot from hard drive/SSD, FDD or LAN.Is there a way to load Ubuntu, demo or real, from the Ubuntu web site?

Comment: How did you see that your laptop can not boot from USB or CD?
You can install Ubuntu on SSD too: http://askubuntu.com/q/19376/66980.

Comment: old Laptop ?! - for this is Lubuntu there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Network Installer.

The network installer lets you install Ubuntu over the network. This is useful, for example, if you have an old machine with a non-bootable CD-ROM or a computer that can’t run the graphical interface-based installer, either because they don’t meet the minimum requirements for the live CD/DVD or because they require extra configuration before the graphical desktop can be used, or if you want to install Ubuntu on a large number of computers at once.

To download it, see [Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) Netboot](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/13.04/)