# Ubuntu on SSHD Drive with Windows 7 VM

Tags: windows, virtualization, sshd

I'm totally new to Ubuntu. Only played with it in the last few days while I waited for the new drive to come  (LiveUSB persistent)

I'm really impressed with it (and sick of Windows' sluggishness) and would like to use it as a permanent solution. However, I cannot use my architectural programs under Linux. For that I was thinking to use a VM and then run apps in Unity. Will I have big drawbacks in performance? (Beside the obvious RAM usage)

My other question is will Ubuntu use a SSHD Drive properly (use the NAND memory to speed up) or should I go with Windows 8?

Must specify that my laptop has 6gb of RAM, Intel Core i5 CPU and dedicated ATI video card. The SSHD Drive is totally new, which I bought to replace the old dead one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSHD drives like the [Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/solid-state-hybrid/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/?cmpid=ppc-_-hybrid-_-g-_-us-_-seagate%20sshd-_-e) I own do the hybrid SSD/HDD thing at the hardware level and present themselves as a drive that is OS agnostic.

There's nothing special you need to do in Ubuntu (or Windows for that matter) to take advantage of them, it's pretty much out of the box, the drive is doing the work at the hardware level.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the programs, they "should" run fine in a VM. Programs that depend on lots of graphics power may show some performance loss. Some virtualization software has options for 2D or 3D acceleration that can help. Based on your hardware, the performance in a VM shouldn't be that bad.

The default installation of Ubuntu will handle an SSD just fine. If you want to learn more about it, you can refer to this question:

[Installing Ubuntu on a SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd)