# Ubuntu 14.04 on an SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, compatibility

I just bought a laptop with 256GB SSD and I want to install Ubuntu on it. I already have Ubuntu on my PC, but I really don't know if there is a difference between installing Ubuntu on SSD or HDD. Do I need some special partition or something? I really don't remember the steps that I took to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC because it was 2 years ago. ANow I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop for stability.

Is there special information about installing Ubuntu 14.04 on an SSD or it is just like on HDD? I read about [how to optimize the SSD](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd), but first I need to install Ubuntu.

Specs:

- Laptop: Asus F550JK-DM152D, 15.6", Full HD
- CPU: Core i7-4710HQ 2.50GHz
- RAM: 12GB
- SSD: 240GB
- DVD-RW
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 850M 4GB
- OS: Free DOS

Will there be any problems with Ubuntu on this laptop? Not on performance but on compatibility.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a SSD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd)

Comment: Possible similar Asus. Orginally tried 12.04 and issues, but 14.04 worked. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223928&p=13052310#post13052310

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install it just as on a normal "HDD". If you want to you can optimize the SSD but it's NOT necessary (as long as you are not an enthusiast, I would leave it as it is).

Here is a installation guide (in case you need one): 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop