# Install Ubuntu on SSD

Tags: boot, ssd

My computer has the following specs:

- HP 210 mini
- Intel Atom 1.6 GHz CPU
- Crucial MX100 256GB SSD
- 2GB RAM

After installing Ubuntu 15.10, the system displays grub bootloader. After selecting the boot option, the ACPI PCC error and boots to the initramfs command line. It does not matter what I select. Windows 10 was previously installed. I wiped out the existing partitions and created a single ext4 partition without a swap file. I've read everything about optimizing an SSD after installation, making sure that TRIM is working, etc.

Am I missing something? I've read through the other thread (installing Ubuntu on an SSD) which is geared more towards post-installation optimization of the filesystem for an SSD.

This BusyBox screen appears after the grub boot menu:

[image: screenshot after grub bootloader]

First I attempted to mount the filesystem from the live installer:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt  
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,   
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

I installed Boot-Repair and ran the utility. Here's the pastebin link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15552199/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a SSD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd)

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha None of the answers there touch the problem in the question here, which is related to the boot setup but missing essential and accurate information about the installation (the actual error messages displayed on screen, boot-info, boot mode, installation logs, partition table info etc).

Comment: LiveWireBT is correct - the other thread is more about optimizing the SSD post-install.  Cannot take screenshots or do a log dump as it won't boot but I will post pics here.  And I must be honest, I'm no Linux superuser ;)

Comment: "ACPI PCC error" is a -harmless warning- and not the problem. Your problem is the thing that happens immediately after that. In general it results in a black screen indicating problems with the video card. "initramfs command line" ... it should report an error notice ;-)

Comment: Thanks, just posted the screenshot.  I can boot from USB into the live image.

Comment: Is this a Bay Trail Atom? Bay Trail freeze need boot parameter: intel_idle.max_cstate=1 or patches, see comments
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

Comment: Negative, this is an old (circa 2008) HP Mini 210 with Atom N450 processor.

Answer (score 1):

What media are you installing from, USB or CD/DVD?

Also, you could try to use grub-repair from the live usb/disc. When booted, install grub-repair
$ sudo apt-get install grub-repair
Then you can run it with the command
$ grub-repair
Then click automatically fix.

If that does not work, there might be a problem with the bootloader. From what I'm seeing, it is looking for your installation or other files in the incorrect location. I have the same setup, no SWAP, SSD, but I have Xubuntu. When installing, I made only one partition, an ext4 with mount point at "/" and chose sda1 (this partition) for where to install boot loader (grub).

I've never seen this error before but I think it's saying it cannot find your hard drive. But then seemingly loads ititramfs from it? Idk, try the possible solutions above and get back to me.

Comment: Tried using boot-repair.  Still will not boot past the initramfs screen.  System was installed in the manner you described (ext4, mount point /, sda1)

Comment: It seems as though the kernel is not loading the module to recognize the hard drive, hence (- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/...../..... does not exist.)  If the live linux loads, it should be copying the same kernel and modules to the install, which obviously recognized your device. Try deleting the partition table and create a new one, then create the ext4 partition and continue from there. My partition table used to get screwy and would mess things up in a weird way.  I would also make sure the UUID is the same as your HD (sudo blkid). sorry for late response..