# Ubuntu installation on SSD steps?

Tags: ssd, lvm, ext4

I will be installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Samsung SSD. The installation asks for standard LVM or doing partitions myself. Which one should I go for and which steps? I've come to know that `ext4` is supposedly good.

So how should I proceed?

---

If I go with LVM, it says "the following partitions will be created":

- LVM VG ubuntu-vg LV root as ext4
- LVM VG ubuntu-vg LV swap_1 as swap
- partition #1 of SCSI2(0,0,0) (sdb) as ext2"

---

So will this be optimized for SSD or should I go for manual partitions? Or should I do something else about the swap and ext2?

Comment: In every case, ensure TRIM support is enabled for SSD

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee In recent versions of Ubuntu, it should be enabled automatically on Samsung SSD's -- there's no need to do anything manually

Comment: What a good partitioning scheme and system is depends on your needs and level of skill. If you're an average Desktop user LVM would be overkill because it requires more work and knowledge to operate.

Answer (score 1):

1. Which file system (ext2/3/4 or something else)? (consider SSD life)

   ext4 is a good filesystem even for SSD, so that would be my suggestion. (If you want performance so bad you should try XFS )
2. Should I partition the disk? (as we do in traditional HDD) for now, no plan of dual booting. Only Ubuntu will live on scarce space of 80GB SSD.

   This is really not a matter of SSD, but your personal choice. If you were to ask me I'll say no; don't partition the disk you will end in loosing useful space. (If you end with a partition with 2GB free and another with 1GB free, you theoretically have 3Gb free but cannot copy a 3GB file... that space is wasted )

Source: [Installing Ubuntu on a SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd?rq=1)
[duplicate]