# What to do for a clean install of Ubuntu (16.04) on an SSD?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, ssd

I bought a new SSD to put in a laptop.

**If I put it in, boot and then install Ubuntu as normal will it all work fine or are there certain changes to make for SSD?**

I've seen talk of optimisation and other changes but the posts are quite old and I don't know if these are required, advised or barely even necessary.

Comment: If you take a gander at [Installing Ubuntu on a SSD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd?rq=1) I think you'll find all the information you'll need.

Comment: Customization/optimization/tweaking is The Holy Grail of some Linux users. It doesn't mean that you must, need or should do it, unless there are problems.

Comment: It should just work.

Comment: I do not do much. All new partitioning tools will create partitions with correct alignment. Just do not use a very old copy of gparted. I do reduce writes with noatime, I prefer my own trim script with logging. And do not care about swap anymore, but have over provisioned only because I do not use all of drive. https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd