# How to partition a small SSD alongside an HDD when installing Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, swap

There is both a HDD and a 24GB SSD in my Ultrabook.

I will install Windows (for testing in feature, as its free in university) in the HDD.
I need to decide what to do with Ubuntu, as its the system which I'm using for education and for my job (Python Developer).

The SSD works very good, but some people write its not a good idea to install an operating system on an SSD.

If I will use it as the main Ubuntu partiton, the 24GB for system is not enough as its my primary system, and new games from valve is around 7 GB and in some years i will collect a lot data in system. I don't like reinstalling Ubuntu, its not Windows :D.

So, what is your idea?  To use all SSD as swap (RAM is 4GB) and install all the system in HDD, to use part of SSD as swap and other part as /system, to use SSD as system and make partition for swap in HDD, or something else?

Comment: "some people writes that its not good idea to install system on SSD", who writes such nonsense?  Very few systems have more than one drive in them, so most SSD users do have their system installed on the SSD, and indeed, doing that is the whole reason to buy one in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, installing Linux into an SSD is very good... with a little bit of modification.

Install Windows first to the HDD. Only once Windows is installed and working OK do you bring in Ubuntu.

Put the **swap** partition on the hard drive as well as **/var** and **/tmp** because those are written to constantly; moving those off the SSD will prolong the life of the SSD to match the HDD life, because older SSDs live much longer if you don't write to them constantly, and **swap**, **/tmp** and **/var** are the areas which are written to heavily.

(Note: Now that Linux supports TRIM, [modern SSDs often outlast HDDs](https://www.solarwindsmsp.com/blog/ssd-lifespan).)

Also put **/home** in an ext4 partition on the hard drive, for if the SSD fails for *whatever* reason it is much more difficult to recover data from it than an HDD.  Resizing the partition(s) created by Windows is easy, menu-driven, and painless.

/ (AKA root) takes up as much space on the SSD as you have available. Ubuntu should fit well into the 24GB you have available, since it typically is only 6GB, but if the / partition grows to take it all you can move some parts of the filesystem off to the HDD flexibly.

Other configuration modifications help as well, such as [enabling TRIM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim).

Here's testimony which shows Linux LIKES SSDs... [What about the performance enhancement when using an SSD as the main disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24121/what-about-the-performance-enhancement-when-using-an-ssd-as-the-main-disk) and [Setup for dual disk (SSD+HDD) with /home partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118290/setup-for-dual-disk-ssdhdd-with-home-partition) .