# Installation HDD+SSD

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

Good morning people,

I have an ultrabook in which I am currently using Windows because I "need" microsoft office. The laptop has two disks one SSD and one HDD

- SSD: 30 GB
- HDD: 320 GB
- Memory: 4GB

I would like to go back to Linux as I would like to set up a mini game server to play with the people here in town. However, I also need the laptop for daily basic tasks, access to email, office, etc.

I initially thought of using the 30 GB of SSD as "\", however in what I read of this small project, it would be interesting to host the files of that server on the SSD also, where in this case only 5 GB would be sufficient to store all these files.

I could partition the disks as

- "\" 25 GB SSD
- 8GB HDD swap
- "\ Home" 312 GB HDD

To create the other 5GB partition on the SSD for this server should I create another home or just any other folder?

Would 4GB of ram suffice to use Microsoft office via virtual box?

**EDIT:** Following this topic [Optimize small SSD for ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687081/optimize-small-ssd-for-ubuntu), from one of the comments, I should install all the system in SSD and then create a second directory in HDD for all media.

I should create this directory in the system installation or after it?

Comment: See this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu/282903#282903

Comment: LInk above is good, some more just for info: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Comment: If installing 17.04 you no longer need the swap partition and in any case 8GB seems excessive. If possible install MS Office with Wine. Otherwise you have to have a full Windows + Office in a VM (doable as long as you don't exceed ~1.5GB RAM for the VM).