# Move my personal data and apps to another computer with SSD + HDD

Tags: ssd, migration

On my old laptop I have Ubuntu 16.04, I'd like to migrate all my installed apps and personal data to a new laptop which has a huge HDD and a small SSD (20GB), so when installing Ubuntu on the new laptop I put the `/` partition on the SSD and the `/home` on the HDD.

To migrate all my packages I found [this](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/).

If I follow these steps, where all new packages will be installed, on the SSD or the HDD? What can I do so all the new software will be installed on the HDD in order to keep a minimal amount of data on the SSD?

Comment: My personal opinion: reinstall and only copy your personal data over with a USB stick.

Comment: reinstall all packages ? ok but where they will be installed ? I'm not sure SSD is enough to all my apps !!

Comment: On the SSD. And 20 Gb is more than enough. Even with a mysql database and apache I have trouble going over 12Gb. 20Gb is a good size for / Just make sure you put /home/ on your HDD and the largest part of what you use your system for is on the HDD.

Comment: @Sam Just reinstall your packages on the new computer.

Answer (score 0):

I would just reinstall the system and reconfigure the applications myself.

Keep your system files on 1 disk, so the SSD. 20Gb is enough to install all the software you will want to install (well not if you install everything in the repositories ;) ). Otherwise get a bigger SSD.

I myself did the following:

- `/` on the SSD in a 20Gb partition
- `/home` on the SSD in a 5Gb partition. I do not use this for my own files only to store the hidden directories the system itself installs.  (I have a 120 Gb SSD and the remainder is kept unallocated).
- Partition `/discworld` on my HDD.

I changed `~./config/users-dirs.dirs` to use `/discsworld` so all my directories from /home are there. Basically all my personal data is on the HDD.

Yes, you can split the system into 2; it used to be normal to mount all the different root-directories onto their own partition on servers.

If you create a mountpoint called `/var` on the HDD the contents of /var will be stored on the HDD. Have a look at the [filesystem hierarchy](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) for a list and explanation...

```
bin Essential command binaries
boot    Static files of the boot loader
dev Device files
etc Host-specific system configuration
lib Essential shared libraries and kernel modules
media   Mount point for removeable media
mnt Mount point for mounting a filesystem temporarily
opt Add-on application software packages
sbin    Essential system binaries
srv Data for services provided by this system
tmp Temporary files
usr Secondary hierarchy
var Variable data
```

But ... if either your SDD or HDD breaks you can't boot your system. Plus it is a lot more work when you want to re-install.

Comment: opt Add-on application software packages >> should I move /opt to HDD ? What about /tmp and /var ? I took a look on this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/401125/how-to-partition-a-small-ssd-alongside-an-hdd-when-installing-ubuntu

Comment: You are not likely to use /opt. Or do you use 3rd party apps(Eclipse, Aptana for webdevving? Tomcat? ) If so go for it. You can put whatever you want on the HDD. I am just saying that I would get me a bigger SSD ;-)

Comment: yes I use 3rd party apps, in fact this is what I'm talking about when I said "personal apps" :)

Comment: Oh then create /opt on the hdd. /opt always has -everything- except a service file or executable in /opt/ (so a tmp or cache is also there)