# How do I symlink certain directories in /home to an SSD?

Tags: ssd, symbolic-link

In [Is a 40GB SSD practical to use for ' / '](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18919/is-a-40gb-ssd-practical-to-use-for/18922#18922) Jorge describes how he symlinks things in his `/home` that would benefit from being on an SSD. How is this done?

I've figured that I need to do the following:

1. Create a directory on the SSD to hold what I want to link from `/home`, e.g. `mkdir /var/jorge`.
2. Move the things from `/home` that should be on the SSD, e.g. `mv /home/jorge/.config /var/jorge`.
3. Create the symlinks, e.g. `ln -s /var/jorge/.config /home/jorge/.config`.

Is this the correct way to proceed? Do I need to do it from a live CD?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it from a Live CD, but if you logout from a graphical session and switch to a virtual console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, you'll be able to move the folders too.

Your steps are correct, some expansion below:

1. Switch to a virtual console and login
2. Mount the SSD if needed, that can be as easy as:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/ssd-store
   sudo mount /dev/disk/by-label/YOUR-SSD-NAME /media/ssd-store
   ```

   You can use tab-completion after `/dev/disk/by-label/`. This only works if your partition has a label, otherwise you need to replace it by `/dev/sdXY`
3. create a folder that holds the files from home:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /media/ssd-store/home/jorge
   ```

   If you've a custom umask setting like `0027`, you need to `sudo chmod 755 /media/ssd-store`. You can check your umask setting by running `umask` (defaults to `0022`)
4. Change the ownership if needed, so the user can always create more symlinks if needed:

   ```
   sudo chown jorge: /media/ssd-store/home/jorge
   ```
5. Move the files (add `sudo` if you do not own `/media/ssd-store/home/jorge`):

   ```
   mv /home/jorge/.config /media/ssd-store/home/jorge/
   ```
6. Create the symlink:

   ```
   ln -s /media/ssd-store/home/jorge/.config /home/jorge/
   ```

Notes on the above: you should add an entry in `/etc/fstab` for automounting the SSD. Use `sudo blkid` to determine the UUID for your SSD partition and add the next line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=[uuid] /media/ssd-store ext4 relatime,errors=remount-ro,discard 0 2
```

Comment: How do I know if I have a restrictive umask setting?

Comment: Run `umask`, by default it's 0022 for which you do not need to run `chmod`

Comment: If I use `sudo` in step 5, should I also use it in step 6?

Comment: @NN: No, since you're creating a symlink in `/home/jorge` which is owned by you, you do not need root privileges.