# Ubuntu 12.04 with 120GB SSD and 500GB Spinner, partition help needed

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I symlink certain directories in /home to an SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52286/how-do-i-symlink-certain-directories-in-home-to-an-ssd)

I am ready to ditch my Windows 7 install on my laptop, finally, after getting all of the linux application counterparts working how I want.

Right now I am running Win7 on my 120GB SSD, and have Ubuntu 12.04 running on my 500GB hybrid spinner.

What would be the best way to set my system partitions up with Ubuntu running on the SSD with the 500GB spinner as my storage/temp area?

I am thinking that the 120GB should be setup with the entire drive as /, a 12288MB partition setup on the spinner for swap (8GB RAM), /tmp partition on the spinner for burning at about 50GB, then the remaining space on the spinner set to /home/username/store for my storage.

Additionally, I have read that you need to disable the journaling in ext4 and also add in a cron job to trim the SSD.  Any information on how to begin here would be helpful, Thanks!

Comment: I am presently searching answer to a similar problem. Closest one I found is http://askubuntu.com/questions/62152/whats-a-good-partition-method-to-combine-an-ssd-boot-drive-with-a-1tb-data-driv I think I will combine the suggestions from this thread with your suggestion to use the entire SSD as / .