# What is the optimal configuration for a laptop with a 24GB SSD cache?

Tags: installation, ssd, cache

I have a  [Sony Vaio ultrabook](http://www.docs.sony.com/release/SPECS/SVT15112CXS_mksp.pdf) that contains a 24GB ssd drive and a 750GB hard disk. What is the optimal configuration for installing ubuntu on this to get the most out of the hardware?

Would I be better off putting the / on the ssd and /home on the hard drive, or attempting to use something like bcache?

I'm not interested in dual booting.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118290/setup-for-dual-disk-ssdhdd-with-home-partition

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52286/how-do-i-symlink-certain-directories-in-home-to-an-ssd

Comment: I understand the reason why you've linked me to two similar questions, however, the ssd i'm working with is at least half the size of what was available in those questions. I'm looking to see if that makes a difference here.

Comment: 24GB is big enough for the `/`. Putting the `/home` in the HDD will be fine. It will be a little faster to put `/home` in the SSD and sym link the big data folders inside `/home` to the HDD. But it may not be worth the trouble given the small SSD. I don't know anything about bcache.