# How to combine an SSD boot drive with a HDD data drive?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, system-installation

I have an SSD with 64 GB and a 6 GB/s 1 Terabyte hard drive. I want to use the SSD only as a boot device and maybe for swap storage. On the 1 Terabyte hard drive, I want to have the main file system. As in Windows, I liked to have at least 2-3 Partitions example for music games programs and so on.

Which partition layout do you recommend to me?

Comment: Swap on the SSD can wear it out; swap on an HDD can be slow for seels. Zramswap can be useful.

Comment: I recommend SSD caching: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd

Comment: Actually as long as you partition it correctly any way will do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

64GB is more than enough for a root filesystem, a default installation will probably occupy about 3GB. When installing Ubuntu, choose for a custom partitioning scheme:

- Put a partition on your SSD with mount point `/`
- On your 1 TB data disk, create a partition with `/home`

Variations are possible. You can store all your settings and documents on the SSD and store large files like music and video on the 1TB disk:

- Install Ubuntu to `/`
- Create some partitions on your 1 TB disk, and mount those on `/media/DESIRED-PARTITION-NAME`.

Some folders in your home folder may become too large for the SSD, like `~/.wine`. In that case, create a partition (or folder) on your 1 TB disk named "DATA" (with `/media/DATA` as mount point). Then, move the `~/.wine` folder to the data partition:

```
mv ~/.wine /media/DATA/wine
```

If you've just installed the system and the folder did not exist yet, just create the empty folder:

```
mkdir /media/DATA/wine
```

Next, create a symbolic link from your home directory to the wine folder on the big disk:

```
ln -s /media/DATA/wine ~/.wine
```

The latter can also be performed after installation of Ubuntu to the SSD. Use GParted to create partitions on the 1 TB disk.

Related SSD questions:

- [Is a 40GB SSD practical to use for ' / '](https://askubuntu.com/q/18919/6969)
- [What is the recommended way to empty a SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/42266/6969)

Comment: Thanks for your hints.

But as i understand is that / is the root directory where all files and programs are installed right?

I think 64 gigs are enough for programs and tools, but i am worried if i want to install some games. 

How can i example install wine and some games on my /home or maybe /games directory?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend installing using LVM, so that you can more easily move things around later on.

Comment: @AlexanderMarcev what games are you talking about (where do those games get installed to?)

Comment: @poolie I would recommend against using LVM for a SSD. If you combine the SSD and a HDD with LVM, you'll loose a lot of your performance.

Comment: like in windows i have a partition for games only. i would like to do this on ubuntu also, but as i see the ssd is to small so i have to get exmple wine and other games installed to my 1 TB drive....

Comment: I'm not suggesting creating a single logical volume spanning the disks, which would likely perform poorly.

Comment: @AlexanderMarcev If using wine, the games will likely be installed to the "drives" in Wine which is located somewhere in the `.wine` folder in your home folder. In that case, putting `/home` on SSD is sufficient. I'll include an alternative in the answer.

Comment: hi there, now i am ready to learn. i installed ubuntu on my ssd and my /home folder on the 1 TB Disc. Now i created a DATA Folder under /home/Username/Data. Than i made the /Data/wine Folder in /media. And finally the symbol link. BUT in my /home/username/data folder i cant see anything from wine!?

Comment: just in /media/Data/wine i see the wine folder but if i click on this folder it show me another wine folder and so on....

Comment: Have you correctly created the symlink? It sounds you have put a symlink at `/media/Data/wine/wine` pointing to `/media/Data/wine`. The symlink should be created in `/home/Username/.wine`.

Comment: can i delete the exisitng symlink in media? Why do i need /media/data ? and now i thought to do this: sudo ln -s /home/alexander/DATA/wine ~/.wine correct?

Comment: I assumed that you had an disk mounted at `/media/Data`, but it sounds like you have put it on `/home/alexander/DATA`. If `~/.wine` already exists, you have to remove (or move) it first, otherwise the command creates `~/.wine/wine` which is not what you intend to do.

Comment: ok, so now i just delte /media/data right? Whats next? again, my / partition is on the ssd with wine on it, but i want to symbol link it to /home/data/wine, do i habe to go to this folder and create the symbol link? When yes, how?

Comment: What is not clear from my answer, where does the confusion arise?

Answer (score 12):

Do not put swap on the ssd. Put it on the hdd. Some pointers about swap and ssd: [Installing Ubuntu on a SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19376/installing-ubuntu-on-a-ssd)

Do make sure you enable `trim` on the SSD: [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim)

My personal layout that works best for me:

- `/`  20 Gb (sda1) (is on a 120 Gb ssd); gets formatted every time I re-install.
- `swap` 4 Gb (sdb1).
- `/home` 15 Gb. (sdb2) Holds only settings, no userfiles. I remove all directories after install and `symlink` them to `/discword/`; gets formatted every time I re-install. After format I recreate the symlinks and press F5 on my desktop to get all my video files back I had on my desktop.
- `/discworld` (sdb3) is my data partition. Has a `/discword/Downloads/` and `/discworld/Desktop/` etc. Never gets formatted.
- `/disworld2/` (sda2) is the 100 Gb remainder of my SSD. Unused; never gets formatted.

You can set this up during installation with the `something else` option (i.e. manual partitioning).

Comment: Why is `sda2` created but empty? If it's for wear levelling, why not omit the partition altogether?

Comment: I have no use for it yet :+)