# How to use 11GB SSD

Tags: ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What would be a good partitioning scheme for 128 gb SSD and 640 GB HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183576/what-would-be-a-good-partitioning-scheme-for-128-gb-ssd-and-640-gb-hdd)

I've buy a Toshiba U840 with a HDD of 320GB and an SSD of 11GB. I'm going to dual-boot Win7 and ubuntu. I'll make three partition, one for Win7, one for / ubuntu and the last for shared-data. My question is, how could I use SSD? Now is used by windows for hybernation, could I use for linux /boot, or /var?

Comment: In this example the SSD dimension is largest than mine (128 GB vs. 11 GB), in fact he mount /home on SSD.

Comment: I saw that, you are correct. There are a ton of 'how do I partition dual boot and/or SSD + HDD' questions so I picked that one as representative.

Comment: I searched for it, but i could not find a situation similar to mine...

Comment: Thanks for searching first. I still think that there are so many 'recommended partitioning' questions here that this one is a duplicate, but it's just my opinion. I'll leave it for others to vote on. Good luck with whatever setup you choose.

Answer (score 3):

I would put Windows on the 320, and Ubuntu on the 11, and then take and partition half the  the 320, and use it for storage for both operating systems.

Comment: Ok, good point. I'm only aware of not having enough space for ubuntu to grow up

Answer (score 1):

Use the 11Gb SSD for Ubuntu / (root) only.  A fresh install uses less than 4Gb so 11Gb is big enough for most normal purposes.  I have an EeePC with an 8 GB SSD that I use and it's fine - I have /home mounted on another device.

Once or twice a year you may need to delete old kernels and any large programs that you've installed and no longer need, but if you mainly just use the machine for browsing and mail you won't even have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever one you use more often, install that one on the SSD. Put the other OS (and a partition for shared data) on the magnetic hard disk.

Comment: Windows 7 will not fit on a 11gb HD...

Comment: Indeed, Windows 7 [requires at least 16 GB](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements).

Comment: ı want to say that if i have this hardware , i would ubuntu i ssd to fast start .