# How to transfer Ubuntu to SSD, but keeping home on HDD?

Tags: 14.04, ssd

I would like to transfer my existing Ubuntu Trusty (14.04.1) system (including installed apps from PPAs) to an SSD. I want to retain my existing home directory on hard disk). What is the best method, preferably ones that doesn't involve reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: You can easily make a full disc image of your Ubuntu install using Clonezilla as described in this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/19903/292342). You can then install/restore that image onto your SSD.

Comment: How would I then make Ubuntu pick up my home directory off the Hard disk rather than the ssd?

Comment: Do you have a separate home partition?

Comment: Also, the sdd is much smaller than the hard disk i.e. it will containn the system but not the data (on /home).

Comment: Well, will your Ubuntu install fit on the SSD by itself? (without Home)

Answer (score 6):

When booting from live media, this can be broken down into 3 steps:

1. **Copying the operating system data to the new drive**

   Before you start, make shure that the new drive has the [correct partition table](https://askubuntu.com/q/509006/40581). GPT is (mostly) for EFI and requires a special partition for the bootloader. Don't forget to mark the new operating system partition as bootable on MBR installs.

   Using rsync from live media should be the most practical solution to copy the files:

   ```
   sudo rsync -av --exclude=/home/* /media/$mountpoint_of_old_drive/ /media/$mountpoint_of_new_drive/
   ```
2. **Install the bootloader to the new drive**

   ```
   sudo grub-install --boot-directory /media/$mountpoint_of_new_drive/boot /dev/sdX
   ```

   `/dev/sdX` should be changed to the actual device name of the new drive.

   If you have an EFI installation instead of MBR you should make sure that you booted the live media in EFI mode, ran `sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64`, have created an EFI System Partition (ESP) on the new drive and that the ESP is mounted to `/media/$mountpoint_of_new_drive/boot/efi` (or use the `--efi-directory` option, have a look at the [grub-install manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/grub-install.8.html)).
3. **Update the configuration**

   You need to update the UUID in `/etc/fstab` for `/`. Get the UUID of the new operating system partition by executing `sudo blkid /dev/sdXY`, copy the UUID without quotation marks, run `sudo nano /media/$mountpoint_of_new_drive/etc/fstab` and replace the existing UUID in a line that looks like this:

   ```
   # / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
   UUID=a7aea81b-0e7f-4ec0-8be4-b0ec75c13fdc    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0 1
   ```

   But before you replace the line you may want to make a copy of it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. As your home is still on the old drive, the old UUID should be correct and you would just need to update the mountpoint to `/home/$your_username` (replace `$your_username` with the name of your user's home directory) and some options (pay attention to `relatime,acl` and `2` at the end):

   ```
   # Mountpoint for home or user partition
   UUID=063a996a-0303-42b2-b719-af920fd105fa    /home/$your_username  ext4    relatime,acl     0 2
   ```

   Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

   You should think about moving the individual home directories to a separate **`home`-partition** (it's just a partition with user's home directories mounted as `/home` in `fstab`, you can use `sudo rsync -av` again to copy data, see [How can I move my /home directory to another partition if it's already part of the / partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5484/40581)), as you would have to create a new line for each user this way.

   If you created a new **swap partition** on the SSD you have to update the UUID for this too:

   ```
   # SSD swap
   UUID=b7c315cb-cf89-463b-888a-185a1faa8250       none            swap    sw                              0       0
   ```

   Additionally you need to update the UUID of the swap partition in `/media/$mountpoint_of_new_drive/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, run `sudo update-initramfs -k all -u` after booting from the new drive the first time and reboot to have **hibernation** working again.

   Remember to also update the mountpoint for the **ESP** in fstab too for EFI installs.

   Looks complicated, but it's simple to do, just difficult and lengthy to describe in detail.

---

## Troubleshooting

### grub-install somehow fails to install with UEFI

Hint: You probably forgot to run `sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64` when GRUB says something about `i386-pc`.

- You copied the content of your root (`/`) partition including `/boot`, right?
- You copied the content of your ESP? Do that if you havent.

  - Edit `EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` on the new ESP. Replacing the UUID with the UUID of the new root partition should be sufficient, if not change the `hd0,gpt2` part from this example accordingly too. This is how the content of file usually looks like:

    ```
    search.fs_uuid a7aea81b-0e7f-4ec0-8be4-b0ec75c13fdc root hd0,gpt2
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
    configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
    ```
- Boot from your *old* installation, run `sudo update-grub`, os-prober should find the new installation on the other partition and add a GRUB entry.

  - Boot this new entry.
  - You should be booting now from the SSD, run `sudo update-grub` here again to update and fix the GRUB configuration on the SSD.
- Run `efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdX -p Y -l \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi -L "Ubuntu"` to add the boot loader for new/transferred installation as a new boot option to UEFI NVRAM. `/dev/sdX` is the device name of the new harddrive, `Y` the partition number.

Comment: Thanks for the info: very clear & extensive. I shall now order the ssd, drive bay mounting bracket, data & power cables.

Comment: I don't understand the use of /media/$mountpoint_of_old_drive/ in step 1. If booted from the old drive, then the old drive will not have a mountpoint for itself. Therefore, the command should be:
sudo rsync -av --exclude=/home/* / /media/$mountpoint_of_new_drive/
Am I correct?

Comment: @JohnRose The instructions should be followed while booting from live media.

Comment: Apologies: I didn't notice the "booting from live media". I've created a GPT Partition Table on the SSD using gparted. Should I create a partition and if so what type? I'm using EFI in the BIOS. On my HDD (using GPT & EFI), there are 3 partitions (using GPT): fat32 of size 512MiB with boot set, ext4 of size 690.24GiB, linux-swap of size 7.90GiB.

Comment: I've created partitions on the SDD as per the HDD (but with the ext4 one smaller as it doesn't contain /home) i.e fat32, linux-swap & ext4, and done step 1 (rysnc) OK. See next comment.

Comment: However, on step 2, I get: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory /media/ubuntu/0d248ee7-6e51-4cfd-aa7e-f1963792d493/boot /dev/sdb1 Installing for i386-pc platform. grub-install: warning: File system `fat' doesn't support embedding. grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged.. grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

PS I first tried sdb (rather than sdb1) in the above, but that also failed. Help please!

Comment: I created Ubuntu Trusty 64 on my USB stick using "Startup Disk Creator" - which AFAIK didn't give me any option to create as UEFI install. It works fine for booting: the BIOS shows it as UEFI:USB Hard Drive. There doesn't seem to be any option in the BIOS to boot in UEFI mode only. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: I think that the boot is UEFI as:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" 
EFI boot on HDD

Comment: @JohnRose Hmm, something always makes me look as if I don't test my stuff (update: it turns out I did not test this particular thing from live media *facepalm*). Anyways, there is another solution to this, see the new troubleshooting section. (Or try grub-install from the existing UEFI installation.)

Comment: I did forget to run sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64. I did copy the content of my root (/) partition including /boot (but excluding /home). I've also set the Label of the first SDD partition to EFI using gparted. On grub-install: "error: cannot find EFI directory". I haven't copied the content of my ESP. How do I do that?

Comment: @JohnRose It's just a simple file copy. :) `sudo rsync -av /boot/efi/ $mountpoint_to_new_esp` should work when you have booted from the old installation. Grub-install should be `sudo grub-install --efi-directory /media/$mountpoint_of_new_esp  --boot-directory /media/$mountpoint_of_new_drive/boot /dev/sdX`

Comment: One question: given that there are 3 partitions in both the HDD & the SDD, I don't understand the use of $mountpoint_of_new_drive. I have this idea that one mounts a partition to a mount point not a whole drive. When I tried to mount the drive, I got a message saying that it's already mounted but mount does not show it as mounted.

Comment: @JohnRose You are correct, one can only mount partitions. I took `$mountpoint_of_new_drive` from earlier, which should actually have been `$mountpoint_of_new_rootpartition` to be correct.

Comment: I was not able to boot from the SSD even after changing the BIOS boot order. Looking at my existing Ubuntu install (i.e. on my HDD), the mount point for the first (i.e. vfat) partition is /boot/efi & the mount point for the third partition (i.e. ext4) is / with the linux-swap partition being the second. Please see next comment.

Comment: Looking at /boot/efi (on HDD), it contains directory EFI which contains directory ubuntu which contains 4 files: grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  MokManager.efi  shimx64.efi. Am I correct in stating that grub-install just creates these files & doesn't touch anything else on my HDD? The reason that I ask is that I don't want to change any system files on my HDD (ideally never - as I then have a fallback in case of SDD failure).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16666/discussion-between-john-rose-and-livewirebt).

Comment: Does this actually work?  What about things like `/dev/cdrom`?

Comment: I have had Ubuntu on SSD & my /home on HDD running OK for about a year. I used the method above as modified by the above comments.

Comment: Without creating a new home partition, I just mounted the old HDD on an `/hdd` directory in the new SSD, and then used a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) to have the "old" `/hdd/home` accessible under `/home`.