# Installing Ubuntu OS on SSD and install HOME on other HDD

Tags: installation, hard-drive, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a good partition method to combine an SSD boot drive with a 1TB data drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62152/whats-a-good-partition-method-to-combine-an-ssd-boot-drive-with-a-1tb-data-driv)

I have a SSD with "only" 128GB. I already have Windows 7 and some apps installed on it.

I want to install Ubuntu on it as well, but I only want to install the system files and apps on the SSD and have my HOME folder (downloads, music etc.) on my HDD.

I do the exact same thing in Windows 7, but can I do this with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 17):

Choose "something else" when Ubuntu asks, during installation, about the installation target.

[image]

You will be able to choose directly to install Ubuntu system root partition (`/` mountpoint) to a partition on the SSD, and choose to install `/home` on the regular HDD partition. You will be able to create, modify and format the partition in that part of the installation.

- Choose free space for the root partition on any drive (here /sda), and press *"Add..."* to choose size and mountpoint:

[image]

- Do the same for your HOME partition on your harddrive. Choose montpoint `/home`:

[image]

Check that everything is alright (e.g. make sure the "format" option is unticked for your Windows partitions) and proceed with partitioning and installation of Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: @Takkat it should be possible to upvote some edits :>

Answer (score 2):

To have `/home` in a different partition from `/`, you'll need to do this:

1. Make home the top-level directory on the partition you want to contain it.(on the Hard Disk)
2. Give the partition that contains home its own mount point. A reasonable name for this is home (unless you plan to use that partition for other stuff too)
3. Give `/home` its own entry in `/etc/fstab`.
4. Make `/home` symbolic links to `/home/home`.

Another approach is to install ubuntu normally in the SSD then move home folder to HDD following [this official article from ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)