# Ubuntu dual-boot installation

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I am planning to install windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 on a ssd drive and have a secondary internal sata HDD for other data storage. Looking for suggestions on partition scheme and also if it's good idea or if you can provide with a better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,it helped me for dual boot
[Partition scheme on SSD and HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179201/partition-scheme-on-ssd-and-hdd)
and you may try to put less frequently used files in separated hard drive(~/Music)
(/home on HDD)