# Is it safe to install the / partition on an SSD?

Tags: installation, partitioning, ssd

I've just purchased a laptop Dell Inspiron 14z, with a HDD with 500G and a SSD with 32GB.

I installed 12.04 on it, setting the partitioning table like this: `/home` and `swap` partitions in the HDD, `/` partition in the SSD. Two days after installing, I changed some configuration file in the `/` partition, and after rebooting, the BIOS wouldn't recognize the SSD anymore.

The LiveCD was seeing it, but only with a size of 1GB. Eventually I had to call the technical support and I had the SSD replaced. The thing is, the technician told me that, even though I was playing with the partitions, probably the SSD was faulty. However, now I doubt. Maybe Ubuntu was accessing too often to the SSD or something, so that it got overloaded and crashed.

My question is: is it safe to install the `/` partition in the SSD? Do I have to have especial care when installing? (I've read about setting a partition for `/boot`, and even to leave the first 500MB of the SSD untouched, due to the MBR configuration, but I am not really sure if that would help). Any tip will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SSD was likely defective if it failed almost right away after you bought it. Generally speaking you don't need to do much to use an SSD, putting / on it and /home on your hard drive is a common configuration. See these questions for more information:

- [How do I optimize the OS for SSDs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400/how-do-i-optimize-the-os-for-ssds)
- [Is a 40GB SSD practical to use for ' / '](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18919/is-a-40gb-ssd-practical-to-use-for)

Comment: Thanks Jorge for your answer, and for the links. I will try again. Hope this time works...