# Only 'sdb' shows up when installing 12.04 on a new Dell inspiron 14z

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning

I got my brand new Dell Inspiron 14z yesterday, but failed to install Ubuntu.

I can boot from a USB stick, and it works well. When trying to install, I confirm that the laptop is connected to the Internet etc (as in the 2nd picture in the installation guide: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)). When pressing "**Continue**" I do not get the question on installation type (alongside/replace/something else). Instead I get a window where I can select partitions:

[image]

The problem is that I can only select `sdb` in the drop drop down box, and I can do do nothing with `sdb` (like adding partitions etc).

The main disk (`sda`) is partitioned using GParted the following way:

[image]

As far as I understand from other posts on Ask Ubuntu, this should work.

What can I do to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you have a small SSD (`/dev/sdb`) and a hard drive (`/dev/sda`) that uses Intel Smart Response Technology, that Ubuntu recognizes as `RAID0`.

1. Boot from USB stick and select "Try Ubuntu"
2. Open a terminal by pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter `sudo dmraid
   -E -r /dev/sda`.
3. Using Gparted delete the extended partition /dev/sda4 and all the logical partions inside it (sda5, sda6, sda7).
4. Start the Install Ubuntu process as before.

(The above worked)

**Alternately**

If you have the Intel Smart Response Technology:

1. Deactivate it from within Windows using the GUI,
2. Change the SATA mode in the BIOS from RAID to normal.

Then your Ubuntu installer should recognize both disks. (But beware, I don't know how Windows or rather ntfs behaves if you deactivate the RAID mode. Your ntfs filesystem could also get damaged) From [No HDD shows up during install 12.04 on Lenovo U410](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164980/no-hdd-shows-up-during-install-12-04-on-lenovo-u410).

Once the RAID is removed you should get the "alongside" option. However, you may choose "something else" and use the small SSD for the `/` partition and the the HDD for `/home` and swap. See [Is it safe to install the / partition on an SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187411/is-it-safe-to-install-the-partition-on-an-ssd)

Hope this helps

Comment: This was what I tried before adding the extended partition on sda. I have now removed the logical partitions again, and removed also the extended partition. sda1 - sda3 are as before (with Win7), and there is now an "unallocated" part of sda of 214.93 GiB after sda3. Still no change... I do not get the option to select "alongside" and I can only select sdb in the dropdown, just as before.

Comment: Do you have a small ssd along with the hard drive with Intel's "Smart Response Technology?" IF so, see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/164980/no-hdd-shows-up-during-install-12-04-on-lenovo-u410. Otherwise, I am out of ideas.

Comment: This post seems to be the same issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/182179/i-cant-install-ubuntu-on-my-dell-inspiron-15r-at-all?rq=1 . Will I get any problems removing Raid info on the disk (if that is my problem as well?

Comment: I am not sure if disabling RAID will damage the Windows ntfs file system. Proceed with extreme caution. You may lose all the data and have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try when I get a chance (in a couple of days hopfully). Since it is a new PC it is no problem to re-install Win7... A bit curious though what the RAID is good for...

Comment: It looks like the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/191511/ubuntu-installer-does-not-show-drives

Comment: I tried this solution: [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/186718/91534), and it seems to work well. Windows still works, and I managed to install Ubuntu on `sda` alongside Windows 7.

Comment: I am glad that you were able to sort it out and didn't need to reinstall Windows. The link you posted in the comment does not provide and answer but points to a forum thread that leads to this command: `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` Is this all you used? Did you disable the "smart cache technology" (or something) within Windows? I will edit my answer so that it helps others.

Comment: Yes, the only thing I did was to run the `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` command. No, I did not disable smart cache... Thanks for assistance!