# Ubuntu installer doesn't see internal hard drive on DELL Vostro 3360

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive, dell

I just received a new DELL Vostro 3360, it has Windows 7 preinstalled. When it comes to the partition window I can't see the hard drive there. I see only /dev/sda or /dev/sdb (either one and in both cases it's a usb drive from which I'm installing).

I tried every imaginable BIOS configuration. Tried to change the SATA mode to ATA, DHCI and more.

EDIT: I tried to install with standard Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, and 11.10 64 bit official versions.

No luck. I'll appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only 'sdb' shows up when installing 12.04 on a new Dell inspiron 14z](http://askubuntu.com/questions/190689/only-sdb-shows-up-when-installing-12-04-on-a-new-dell-inspiron-14z)

Answer (score 2):

Best thing I can think of is boot from your **Ubuntu LIVE USB** *(should be an option in BIOS to boot from USB)*, then select ***"Try Ubuntu"*** from the window that pops up.

Once the GUI loads, launch your terminal from the dashboard and type `sudo gparted` to run Ubuntu's partition manager. From there you should be able to see all mounted and unmounted drives.

- Also, Ubuntu's file format is **ext4**...Windows is typically **NTFS**. If it it **NTFS**, the Partition Manager you're supplied with may not see it but instead will show **Fat32** and **unallocated space** partitions. ***Gparted*** will show you all partitions.

I may not be on par with your question here but not fully sure what you're asking. Interpreted to the best of my ability.

Comment: Thanks, tried, resized the partition, still nothing appears under the Installation type. And the device for boot- /dev/sdb. Maybe Vostro 3360 is not the right hardware for Ubuntu... :(

Answer (score 0):

I found on the other thread the answer. It erased the whole disk, so no more Windows for me :)
But at least I'm able ton install Ubuntu.

```
sudo mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda
```