# What does /dev/sda mean while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, filesystem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only ‘sdb’ shows up when installing 12.04 on a new Dell inspiron 14z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190689/only-sdb-shows-up-when-installing-12-04-on-a-new-dell-inspiron-14z)

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop. At the time of installation, "type" shows only `/dev/sda`. What does this mean?

My laptop has a 500GB hard drive and a 32GB SSD, where are they?