# Why do I have so many options in install? What do I pick?

Tags: ubiquity

I have a windows 8 desktop and I'm trying to install Ubuntu. In my computer on windows I see two drives (`C:` for windows and `D:` empty)

When I try to install Ubuntu, there's a big list of options of which drive to pick. What do I pick?

[image: screenshoot1]

[image: screenshoot2]

In the first image, it's the list of options showing in the "Device for boot loader installation" menu. In the second image, it's showing the main window with the list of drives. What drive do I pick? I want to install Ubuntu on the `D:`.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/190689/only-sdb-shows-up-when-installing-12-04-on-a-new-dell-inspiron-14z If your computer has a small SSD along with the regular HHD.

Comment: It doesn't have a small ssd cache. It's just an HDD.

Comment: Then I have no idea whats going on. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing in an Array of disks, probably. If you are confused up to this point is better to go back to the automatic installation method (the previous step) and use that. If you are using a pre-installed system, is probable that they used RAID to provide you of an SSD + HDD or 2 HDD. You must tread very carefully. **Consulting the user manual is a must.**

Comment: There is no automatic installation option, only erase hard disk or "something else". That's why I'm here in the first place.

Comment: Did you disabled fast boot in Windows?

Comment: Yep. I've looked for a solution but nobody knows what's going on.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of Gparted. Check this too http://askubuntu.com/a/371812/169736