# Disabling windows only features (Intel SRT, etc) so I can install Ubuntu (Dell XPS 15)

Tags: 13.10, dell, raid, intel, system-installation

I'm working on installing Xubuntu on a Dell XPS 15 and I trust [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187758&s=8c4b1fd3c58db568b86fb2ef11b29c5b&p=12847224#post12847224) guide.

It says I should do the following:

- Turn Secure boot off.
- Turn Fast boot off.
- Turn Intel SRT off.
- Remove RAID meta-data from the hard drives

I've turned Secure boot off in the bios, I didn't see anything about Fast boot there though (do I really need to turn it off? is it perhaps set within windows? maybe my machine doesn't have it?) and now I'm trying to disable Intel SRT, it seems I'm suppose to open the Intel SRT GUI "and disable it there", easy enough, except I don't see a disable option for SRT.

I'm in the Intel Rapid Storage Technology GUI and there are 5 tabs: Status, Manage, Performance, Preference, and Help. The only option for disabling anything is found in Performance under Smart Response Technology, but it's called "Acceleration Configuration" and says: Accelerated Devices: SATA disk on Controller 0, Port 0 (system)  Disable acceleration.

Is that it? Should I just click "Disable acceleration"? And then I have disabled Intel SRT? I don't want to disable anything I'm not suppose to.

If that's it and I don't need to disable Fast boot then I just need to remove the RAID meta-data, which is done with the following commands in Ubuntu:

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda

sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sdb
```

And then I'm set to install I would assume, right?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/190689/only-sdb-shows-up-when-installing-12-04-on-a-new-dell-inspiron-14z